# WP Redirect with Wild Card Characters

Tags: redirect

I am using wp_redirect() to restrict access to logged out users and redirect them to login page. Here's my code which works perfecly.

```
function loggedout_post_redirect(){
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_single() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() . '/login/' ) ;
        exit();
    }
}
add_action ( 'template_redirect', 'loggedout_post_redirect' );
```

But what if, I want to redirect all logged out users who access this specific URLs?

- [www.example.com/users/UserProfileA](http://www.example.com/users/UserProfileA)
- [www.example.com/users/UserProfileB](http://www.example.com/users/UserProfileB)
- [www.example.com/users/UserProfileC](http://www.example.com/users/UserProfileC)
- ..
- ..
- ..
- [www.example.com/users/UserProfileZ](http://www.example.com/users/UserProfileZ)

please note that the "www.example.com/users/" doesnt change, the only changing characters are the UserProfileA-Z. Where UserProfileA - Z is equal to the usernames of my WordPress users.

I've tried using is_page() with wild card (user/)* but it's not working.

```
function loggedout_user_redirect(){
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page('user/*') ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() . '/login/' ) ;
        exit();
    }
}
add_action ( 'template_redirect', 'loggedout_user_redirect' );
```

any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a regex if you do not use query variables from WordPress.

Here is an example:

```
function loggedout_user_redirect(){

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $regex = '~/users/(.*)~';
        $url   = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        
        preg_match( $regex, $url, $matches );
        
        if ( isset( $matches[1] ) && '' !== trim( $matches[1] ) ) {
            wp_redirect( site_url( '/login' ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action ( 'template_redirect', 'loggedout_user_redirect' );
```